# Role of router as an DHCP server When provided with static IP

Tags: networking

I want to set up an i-Ball Baton router as a dhcp server. But the problem is i get Static IP at the WAN Port. Will getting a static IP at the wan port affect its role as a dhcp server ? . I will be connecting 2-3 devices that will require dynamic ip from the router.

Answer (score 0):

**No, it won't affect**. Some networking basics:

Router is a [gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_gateway) device, it's located between two network segments thus connecting them:

1. local area network (LAN) - place where all your devices live
2. wide area network (WAN) - all outer world

Since router belongs to two networks simultaneously, it has two absolutely independent IP addresses for each one. Router's job is to receive packets from Internet on WAN interface and inject them into LAN and vice versa. So LAN is quite isolated from the Internet, you can always drastically change LAN layout while still appearing to the outer world as the same single IP address.

DHCP server feature is intended for organizing addresses on your LAN, it doesn't rely on WAN interface details.